# Optimising performance of WCF service under sudden load

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, wcf, load

I am developing a C# WCF service which calls a backend c# server application.

We are running performance tests on the service.

For example each test might consist of these steps
- Logon
- Create application object ( gets created in Sql database by server application )
- Delete application object
- Logoff

We run the test with 100 concurrent users ( ie unique client threads ) with no ramp up and no user wait time between test steps

We have done quite a bit of optimisation on the server side, so that the tests run quite well when we run them repeatedly - say 100 concurrent threads, each thread repeats the test steps 25 times - results of typically about average 1 second response time for each step in the test which is OK.

However when we run tests with 100 concurrent users but only run the tests once in each thread, the results are inconsistent - sometimes the test steps may take quite a bit longer average elapsed time could be 5 seconds for a step in the test.

It appears that under a sudden burst of activity, the service returns inconsistent performance results.

I have tried several things to optimise performance

( for compatibility with the client the WCF binding has to be BasicHttpBinding )

- varying the serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls and maxConcurrentSessions parameters in the WCF configuration
- using a semaphore to limit the number of concurrent requests inside the Wcf service
- implementing the methods inside the wcf service as Tasks ( .net version is 4.5 )
- making the methods async tasks
- tuning the size of the ThreadPool using setMinThreads
- using a custom attribute to extend WCF to implement a custom ThreadPool as per this Msdn article ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163321.aspx )

I have found that running tests and varying parameters can be used to tune the application performance, but we still have the problem that performance results are poorer and more inconsistent when we run say 100 concurrent client threads repeating the test steps 1 time.

My question is : what are the best ways of tuning a c# WCF service so it will respond well to a sudden burst of client activity ?

Thanks.

Comment: make sure IIS host is able to handle high amount of concurrency connections. Then if this is already done and it doesn't help look into Load Balancing with WCF. i used to have done it in the past using 3 servers. If this is still not enought you have ALOT of data going on and might be looking into external hosting on cloud node type server or azure hosting.

Comment: Are you generating the test load from a single computer?  My guess is that it can only generate a load so fast and only one test per thread is a different type of load and a harder load for the service to handle.

Answer (score 1):

Decided to post as answer instead so here the good thing to do :

1 - Check concurency connection. Sometime small server might be limited between 2 and 50  which is very low. your server admin should know what to do.

2 - Load balancing with WCF is possible and help alot when split over multiple servers.

3 - Have the IIS host server ONLY doing IIS work. i.e dont have SQL running on it either

4 - Do not open WCF service connection, query, close connection every single request. an handshake is needed every single time and over time with multiple user it become alot of time lost because of that. Instead open the connection once when the application start and close on exit (or error obviously)

5 - Use smaller type inside the service. Try avoiding type such as decimal, int64. Decimal is 128 bits and int64 is 64 bits and perform much slower than float/double/int. Obviously if you absolutely need to use them use them but try to limit.

6 - A single big method make the overall timing slower for everyone as the waiting line grow faster and slow IIS and might loose new connections if you have alot of user because of timeout. But smaller methods will take longer for everyone because of the extra back and forth of data BUT user will see more progress that way and will feel the software is faster even though it is really not.

BasicHttpbinding works great in anycase